# Как получить статистику по инстаграм аккаунту python

Tags: python, selenium, instagram, instapy

Пишу аналитику на python по инстаграм , но столкнулся с проблемой что просто не могу получить все данный об аккаунте , кол-во подписчиков, лайков, комментариев ,пробовал через API не дают доступ , пробовал библиотеку InstagramApi перерыл весь интернет но так ничего не подошло и не сработало , есть ли варианты получить эти данные ?

Comment: Если в официальном Instagram API описанном в документации разработчика нет нужных функций, то их точно не найти в библиотеках тоже, т.к. библиотеки используют подмножество API. Но мне кажется такие вещи точно должны быть в API, пвё просмотрели? Альтернативный способ это качать HTML страницы каждого пользователя в веб или мобайл инстаграммах и парсить их на предмет нужных полей.

Comment: да я щас начал парсить каждый пост и собирать кол-во лайков , комментариев , а кол-во подписок сразу написано поэтому легко извлечь